# What is the meaning of 'concatenate' in this neural network architecture?

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I am trying to understand the lane edge proposal network proposed in [LaneNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01726) for lane detection.[image: Network architecture]

My understanding of this is that a number of convolutional and pooling layers are first used to downsample the input images into feature maps, and then three deconvolutional layers (using sub-pixel convolution) are used to upsample back to original image size.

What I don't understand is the dashed 'concatenate' arrows between equally sized conv/deconv layers, they are not mentioned outside this diagram.

Also, the paper also states "*Skip connections are used to provide high resolution feature for accurate lane edge localization*", but no mention is made of skip connections elsewhere in the paper. My understanding of skip connections is with regard to residual blocks, which doesn't seem to link to this diagram. Unless the concatenate arrows are skip connections? In which case my earlier assumption, that input images simply pass through each conv and deconv block in order, no longer holds.

Comment: I think it should have a similiar role like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxhSouuSZDY